# Issue with filtering and vba

Tags: vba, excel

Essentially I've created a reporting dashboard at work using Adobe's Report Builder tool, and then I use the VBA macro below to update my report builder queries and refresh my pivot tables:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

 Dim addIn As COMAddIn
 Dim automationObject As Object
 Dim success As String
 Set addIn = Application.COMAddIns("ReportBuilderAddIn.Connect")
 Set automationObject = addIn.Object
 success = automationObject.RefreshAllRequests(ActiveWorkbook)

 Dim PT As PivotTable
 Dim WS As Worksheet

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
          PT.RefreshTable
        Next PT

 Next WS

End Sub
```

The macro seems to be working well, but I initially had an issue with my pivot tables not updating properly. I then found out it was because I had the (blank) row filtered out, which meant that when the pivot table refreshed with a new day's worth of data that day was automatically filtered. Is there any way I can make all my pivot tables update without having the (blank) field on them?

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding this and let me know if this works

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Day")
.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
End With
```

Comment: I've tried running it but I'm getting a "Object doesn't support this property or method". I've replaced the "mention the field name" with "Day" (field name) and "Row Labels" (how it displays on the pivot table) but it doesn't seem to be picking up either.

Comment: I have updated my previous answer above. Pls check that.